# I don't understand why object required error occurs every time in VBA?

Tags: vba

I'm working on a VBA project to determine if PE of a company is too high. I'm relatively inexperienced with vba, however, I cannot find anything wrong with my code, why does excel always return me an object required error? If anyone could help me, thank you!

```
Dim i As Long, pe As Long
Dim result As String

For i = 4 To 10
pe = Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value
        If pe >= 85 Then
            result = "high"
        ElseIf pe >= 75 Then
            result = "mid"
        ElseIf pe >= 55 Then
            result = "low"
        ElseIf pe >= 40 Then
            result = "very low"
        Else
            result = "not in range"
        End If

        Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = result
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have the wrong stackexchange!

Comment: Your code works fine for me (Excel 2016)

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's the wrong stack exchange, you need to add a declaration at the start to dim Sheet1 as Sheet or similar, i think it's complaining that it doesn't know what Sheet1 is at runtime.

Comment: That's because Sheet1 is a variable which has nothing in it (in fact you haven't even declared it.)  You have to declare the variable Sheet1 and set it (the variable) to something, probably a sheet from the Sheets collection from the ActiveWorkbook object.